# Obtener el nombre de la clase dado un atributo de esa misma clase

Tags: python, clase, atributos

Sea una clase como:

```
class color:
  atributos=[('Color',['Rojo','Azul','Verde']),
       ('Forma',['Cuadrado','Redondo']),
       ('Tamaño',['Grande','Pequeño'])]

  atributo_clasificación='Clase'
  clases=['+','-']

  entr=[['Rojo' , 'Cuadrado'        , 'Grande'    , '+' ],
       ['Azul' , 'Cuadrado'        , 'Grande'    , '+'],
       ['Rojo' , 'Redondo'        , 'Pequeño'    , '-'],
       ['Verde', 'Cuadrado'       , 'Pequeño'    , '-' ],
       ['Rojo'  , 'Redondo'        , 'Grande'  , '+' ],
       ['Verde'  , 'Cuadrado'        , 'Grande'  , '-']]
```

Me gustaria saber si tengo **color.entr** como puedo obtener el nombre de la clase a la que pertenece. Es decir, que al aplicarle algun tipo de operacion obtenga como resultado: *color*

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que pretendes. `color.entr` es una lista, ¿a qué *clase* te refieres cuando dices: *como puedo obtener el nombre de la clase a la que pertenece*?

Comment: Si, color.entr es una lista pero si no me equivoco tambien es un atributo de la clase color. Y quiero saber como obtener el nombre de la clase a la que pertenece ese atributo

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que quiere es instanciar un objeto con esa clase y preguntarle a dicho objeto, a que clase pertenece. Si es este el caso te pongo aquí dos ejemplos:

```
#Creamos una clase Color
class Color():
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

#Instanciamos un objeto  "a"
a = Color('rojo')


#Preguntamos a "a" cual es la clase a la que pertenece
print(a.__class__.__name__)

#Lo mismo pero de distinta forma
print(type(a).__name__)
```

Comment: No exactamente, creo que no consigo explicarme correctamente. Si pongo color.atributos me devolvera la lista de atributos de modo que si le pregunto por type(color.atributos).__name__ me devolvera que es una lista. Pero yo lo que querria es obtener la clase, es decir que me devuelva color para en caso de estar trabajando con varias clases poder saber de que clase es el atributo que le estoy pasando. Todas las clases tendran los mismos atributos pero seran distintos

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, si puedes editarla arriba, poniendo un ejemplo  de lo que tienes y el resultado que esperas. No sé porque quieres usar un atributo para saber el nombre de una clase, cuando lo puedes saber mediante el propio objeto, sin necesidad de poner el atributo